# RaycastHit not detecting anything

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So when I run a Physics.Raycast, it doesn't detect anything even when there is a collider directly in front of it. No there are no issues with the tag.
My Code:

```
Ray rightRay = new Ray(Right.position, Target.position);
RaycastHit hitInfoRight;
Transform Right;
Transform target;
if (Physics.Raycast(rightRay, out hitInfoRight) && hitInfoRight.transform.tag == "Building")
{
    Debug.DrawLine(Right.position, hitInfoRight.point, Color.red);
} else
{
    Debug.DrawLine(Right.position, target.transform.position, Color.blue);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your Ray is facing the correct direction? Also, I suggest you break the first if condition into nested if during debug to identify the exact error location.

Comment: My Ray is facing towards the target, but it might be an issue because the end point is the target and it might not detect anything else in the way.

Comment: Set the start as your shooting object and the direction towards your target. You might have set the start at your target causing it to fail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [`Ray`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Ray.html) expects

- start **position**
- and a **direction**

You are passing in two positions, which works **only** in the one single case where the first start position equals `0,0,0`.

What you rather want to do is

```
var direction = Target.position - Right.position;
var rightRay = new Ray(Right.position, direction);
```

---

Then in general also rather use [`CompareTag`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.CompareTag.html) instead of `==`. The latter might simply fail silently in case of a typo or non existent tag while `CompareTag` throws an error, making your debugging way easier. Besides that `CompareTag` uses hashes and is slightly faster than a direct `string == string`

---

And then I am also confused because you are once using `Target.position` and once `target.transform.position` so make sure these are the same reference

Comment: Sorry, the capital on target was a mistake when I was rewriting it, but the tips really helped!